# Objective - C aggregate functions related to array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C, is there any aggregate functions are placed in iOS?

If yes, could you provide me how to use those functions?

Comment: array contains dictionaries?

Comment: @Sunny:yes my array contains dictionaries ,in that dictionaries i have marks of the students.i need to calculate total and avg values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some of the aggregate functions ar listed below and try like this

```
[YourArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.marks"] //total value
[YourArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.marks"] //avg value
[YourArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.marks"] //minimum value
[YourArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.marks"] //maximum value
```